# Proof that a set that has supremum property implies it has infimum property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I really have no clue where to start with this proof:

Suppose S is an ordered field and satisfies supremum property.  Show that S has the infimum property as well.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways of doing this.  One of them works with ordered fields; the other with linearly ordered sets in general.

- Show that a non-empty set $A$ that is bounded below has an infimum by showing that $-\sup(-A)$ is that infimum, where $-A = \{-x: x\in A\}$.  This works in ordered fields.  Perhaps you can supply the details I'm omitting.
- Show that a non-empty set $A$ that is bounded below has an infimum by showing that the sumpremum of the set of all lower bounds of $A$ is the infimum of $A$.  This works with ordered sets, not just with ordered fields.  Again, missing details need to be supplied.